# Rxjs: Why this stream of array not recieving new values

Tags: angular, system.reactive, rxjs, rxjs5, subject

I made stream of array using Observable.from() in the constructor and subscribed it in the constructor too, the array is getting update but subscription method is not working i think, I'm not getting console.log for the data, here is the code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input type="text" required 
        [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="inputValue" >  
        <button (click)="addto()">submit</button>  
     })
```

this is class

```
export class first{

 proxySubject;
 inputValue: string;
 array = [];

constructor(){
this.proxySubject = Observable.from(this.array)
this.proxySubject.subscribe(function(data){
       console.log(data))
}

addto(){     
    this.array.push(this.inputValue)
} 
}
```

Comment: That will not pick up new array values, when you call 'from', it takes the values in the array and converts that to a stream immediately.   You probably want to create a 'ReplaySubject' and push the array values to the subject in your constructor, then push new values in addto().

Comment: Nothing happend i converted proxySubject to ReplaySubject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.from()` checks mentioned array only once, every time you create a new subscribtion to given observable. What you are looking for is an observable array. One of the approaches can be creating  custom `addItem()` function which will `.push()` new item to an array and the call `mySubject.next(myArray)`. With this setup you can subscribe to `mySubject` to get notified whenever the content of array changes.

EDIT:

```
myArray = [];

mySubject = new BehaviourSubject(myArray); // store last version for new subscribtions

addItem(item) {
  myArray.push(item);
  mySubject.next(myArray)
}

mySubject.subscribe(arr => console.log(arr))
```

EDIT 2 - observer:

```
// doesnt really help anything
let myObserverRefference;

observable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
  myObserverRefference = observer;
});

addItem() {
   myObserverRefference.next(myArray);
}
```

Comment: I have addTo method that pushes new value to the array, lets forget about the subject for the time being with next method

Comment: This will never happen automatically u have to notify `subject` to emit next value or write custom `observer` as in `new Obserable(observer => { /* ... */ observer.next(myArray); })`

Comment: every time array changes with push method in the addto method will it not be detected by observable.from(),

Comment: No, you have to notify `subject` or custom `observer` manualy. This doesnt work automatically.

Comment: could you give me example

Comment: :) could you give me with observer version

Comment: I recommend you to use subject. If you don;t want to expose `subject` make it private and expose only `public myObservable = mySubject.asObservable()`.

Comment: If you write custom observer you are basically reimplementing subject's interface by yourself.

Comment: okay, i will try with observer (for practice purpose) because i have already with subject, Thank you, if there is need of help i will get back to you ;)

Comment: No worries, also please upvote the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is worth nothing that in knockout.js this is core functionality, and often only few lines of code with all of bells and whistles of array / object change events you want right there. Why things tend do get overcomplicated for such trivial tasks i'm not getting it.